# Getting Exception while trying to execute axis2 service client

Tags: apache-axis

I am trying to create a sample axis2 ServiceClient. It is throwing below error

```
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: No meta factory found for feature 'default'; this usually means that axiom-impl.jar is not in the classpath
    at org.apache.axiom.om.OMAbstractFactory.getMetaFactory(OMAbstractFactory.java:170)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.OMAbstractFactory.getMetaFactory(OMAbstractFactory.java:135)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.OMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory(OMAbstractFactory.java:184)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisDescription.<init>(AxisDescription.java:68)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration.<init>(AxisConfiguration.java:148)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.populateAxisConfiguration(DeploymentEngine.java:639)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.FileSystemConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(FileSystemConfigurator.java:116)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:68)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:184)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.configureServiceClient(ServiceClient.java:150)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.<init>(ServiceClient.java:143)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.<init>(ServiceClient.java:244)
    at org.apache.axis2.samples.tu.client.TUrlSOAPClient.addUrl(TUrlSOAPClient.java:46)
    at org.apache.axis2.samples.tu.client.TUrlClient.actionPerformed(TUrlClient.java:69)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The `axiom-impl.jar` is present in the classpath. Below is the code snippet. In the console I can see that sysout statement "Entered" is displayed, after that its throwing error at ServiceClient object creation. Have tried using different versions of the `axiom-impl.jar` (1.2.12, 1.2.13, 1.2.7, 1.2.5) but still getting the same error.

```
     public static String testFunction(String testData) throws Exception {
     System.out.println("Entered");
    //Create a service client
    ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
    System.out.println("Before calling set end point");
    //Set the endpoint address
    client.getOptions().setTo(new EndpointReference(EPR));
    System.out.println("After calling set end point");
    System.out.println("getPayload(url)="+getPayload(testData));
    //Make the reqest and get the response
    OMElement resp = client.sendReceive(getPayload(testData));
    //Extract the URL and return
    return extractUrl(resp);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this by replacing all the three individual axiom jars( axiom-impl-1.2.13.jar, axiom-dom-1.2.13.jar and axiom-api-1.2.13.jar) by just axiom.jar.

Comment: but why this happens , I still dint get answer for this There is some setting we have in eclipse or tomcat which asks for latest version of axim jars.

Comment: For some reason the same happened to me and I'm still unable to find out the reason why this is caused. Anyways, thank you, you saved my day.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error but finally got solved by using axiom-api 1.2.12 and axiom-impl 1.2.12 after long struggle.

Answer (score 1):

when I use above jar I got another error.
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.factory.OMLinkedListImplFactory

I had to increase version to 1.2.14 of each jar

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I did replace the individual axiom jars( axiom-impl-1.2.13.jar, axiom-dom-1.2.13.jar and axiom-api-1.2.13.jar) by just axiom.jar, but the error still happening.

The root cause of the error was  the location of META-INF/axiom.xml file. In my case, the XMLParser of the J2EE server container can not open the axion.xml file when it be localized within a jar file.

I had to copy META-INF/axiom.xml into WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/axiom.xml .